# Copying all files from one folder to an other with command line in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer

I have two folders `src` and `dest`:

```
src
  --new.txt
  --style.css

dest
  --text.txt
  --install.bat
```

I would like to copy all files inside src into dest. I have tried `copy src dest` but that destroys everything that is inside dest.

Is they a way to copy all files/folders inside src into dest ?

how the dest folder should be after the copy:

```
dest
  --text.txt
  --new.txt
  --style.css
  --install.bat
```

Answer (score 4):

`xcopy /s src\*.* dest` doesn't work for you?

If you specify only the folder, it replaces the entire folder for you. When you specify the items *inside the folder* (with `*.*`), it copies the actual *files* instead of the folder.

Example below:

```
C:\Users\User>xcopy /s test\*.* test2
test\1.txt
test\2.txt
2 File(s) copied

C:\Users\User>dir test2
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3018-ED8A

 Directory of C:\Users\User\test2

06/02/2014  09:38 AM    <DIR>          .
06/02/2014  09:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/02/2014  09:37 AM                 5 1.txt
06/02/2014  09:37 AM                 5 2.txt
06/02/2014  09:37 AM                 5 3.txt
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work either because I would like to copy the folders that are in src too

Comment: @edi9999 edited

Comment: I get "The syntax of the command is incorrect. " My command : `copy C:\\wamp\\www\\poker-tell\\server\\*.* C:\\wamp\\www\\poker-tell\\build\\window /s`

Comment: Why are you using double backslashes? And the `/s` should go before the paths

Comment: This command : `copy /s C:\wamp\www\poker-tell\server\*.* C:\wamp\www\poker-tell\build\window` raises the same error

Comment: Without the /s it works, except that the folders aren't copied

Comment: Whoops, meant xcopy. I need to stop answering on my phone, apparently...

Answer (score 2):

I finally used

```
robocopy src\ dest /E
```

which is able to copy even files with long paths.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should use xcopy command. It copies all file structure within the directory:

```
xcopy src dest /s /e
```

This two parameters instruct it to copy all files directories within src including empty ones

Comment: I get "insufficient memory" (seems that the content of the paths of some of the files exceed 254)

Comment: Well, it's possible. Why do You need it to do in CLI anyway - maybe it's easier to do another way? Using third-party utils?

Comment: I needed it to be done in command line because it's a task I wanted to do often (it's part off the creation of an installer)

Comment: Robocopy is a replacement for xcopy and as such is probably better going forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy scr dest
```

should be enough altough it will not copy subdirectories

if you have same file in the destination folder you should have a message like this one:

```
C:\>copy tmp tmp2
tmp\bifish.txt
tmp\mal.log
Overwrite tmp2\mal.log? (Yes/No/All): no
tmp\png_create_201401.sql
tmp\png_data_201401.sql
        3 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: I would like to copy subdirectories too...